# How long is maximum time to investigate an airplane crash?

Tags: safety, boeing-737, accident-investigation

Lion Air flight 610 was crashed on 29 October 2018. It was Boeing 373 Max 8. Almost one year ago. I have not heard any news from National Transportation Safety Committee (NTSC) when they will release the investigation report to media.

From the previous accident, AirAsia QZ8501 occurred on 28 December 2014 with Airbus A320 airplane, NTSC took less than a year time to release the investigation report to media. On 4 December 2015, the NTSC did the release the report.

Then my question is, how long is maximum time to investigate an airplane crash?

Comment: The NTSB is not investigating that crash because it occurred in Indonesia. The investigation is carried out by the National Transportation Safety Committee (NTSC) of Indonesia. The NTSB has however [sent a representative](https://www.ntsb.gov/investigations/_layouts/ntsb.aviation/brief.aspx?ev_id=20181029X04746&key=1). They have published a [preliminary report](https://reports.aviation-safety.net/2018/20181029-0_B38M_PK-LQP_PRELIMINARY.pdf) so far.

Comment: Thank you for the correction about the NTSC. But what I mean is full report, as they did to AirAsia QZ8501's report.

Answer (score 4):

According to [ICAO](https://www.icao.int/about-icao/FAQ/Pages/icao-frequently-asked-questions-faq-11.aspx), a preliminary report must be released after a year. There is no hard timeline for the full report:

> **What are a State’s reporting obligations during and after an aircraft accident investigation?**
>
> Under Annex 13 to the Chicago Convention, States in charge of an investigation must submit a Preliminary Report to ICAO within thirty days of the date of the accident, unless the Accident/Incident Data Report has been sent by that time. Preliminary Reports may be marked as confidential or remain public at the investigating State’s discretion.
>
> The State conducting the investigation of an accident or incident shall also make the Final Report publicly available as soon as possible and, if possible, within twelve months.
>
> If the report cannot be made publicly available within twelve months, the State conducting the investigation shall make an interim statement publicly available on each anniversary of the occurrence – detailing the progress of the investigation and any safety issues identified.

Keep in mind there is no established penalty for not complying with the above. Indeed [in some cases (or countries)](http://avherald.com/h?article=40fc7579/0002) it can take up to a decade for a final report to be published.

Comment: From your own quote, it is clearly stated that preliminary report must be submitted within 30 days. **an investigation must submit a Preliminary Report to ICAO within thirty days of the date of the accident,** and the final report must be made publicly as soon as possible, but maximum within 12 months. **the investigation of an accident or incident shall also make the Final Report publicly available as soon as possible and, if possible, within twelve months.** So, what I worried about is reasonable as just few more days, the accident will be one year on 29-October 2019 will be one year.

Comment: @AirCraftLover it's impossible to set a limit to the duration of an accident inquiry, as it can take very long to get all the information needed. For example a crash off South Africa took years just to get the equipment needed to access the wreckage which was in deep water (and no suitable deep submersibles were available to the investigators). Other accidents may happen in warzones where access is impossible until the fighting ends. Or it may take decades to even find the wreckage (a few years ago a wreck was found dating back to the 1940s for example).

Comment: @jwenting, if you read the quoted comment of AEhere carefully, there will be mandatory report within 12 months, or public statement about the investigation's progress.

Comment: @AirCraftLover if you read my last paragraph, you'll see that "mandatory" is a meaningless term if there is no way to enforce this mandate. A country can delay in publishing the report, and face little-to-no consequences.